# How to update redis - Django

Tags: django, redis, task, signals

I need help updating my cache. I use redis in my django project.

Is there a way to trigger an auto refresh on redis itself so it performs a look up on the db to make an update on the cache. I am trying to implement this while avoiding signals and tasks.

Is there anyway to trigger an auto refresh for a particular key in redis cache?

Answer (score 0):

cache invalidation is complex problem. There is no one good way to rule them all. As far as i know redis is not capable of trrigering python functions, Redis is just a cache engine storing key, value pairs with ttl. If you want some automation with invalidating cache maby django-cacheops could be of use. [django-cacheops on github](https://github.com/Suor/django-cacheops)

personaly I write my own cache invalidators/ updates. So when a value that you cache is update i update it in cache. when cache hits its ttl the geter method set its again.

it is done in signals for example when someone change model settings with admin_timeout:

```
@receiver(post_save, sender=Settings)
def invalidate_cache_settings(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if instance.name == 'ADMIN_TIMEOUT':
        cache.set('admin_timeout', instance.value_int, 3600)
```

then in custom tag

```
@register.simple_tag(name="admin_timeout")
def get_admin_timeout():
    admin_timeout = cache.get('admin_timeout', None)
    if admin_timeout is None:
        try:
            admin_timeout = Settings.objects.get(name='ADMIN_TIMEOUT').value_int
        except ObjectDoesNotExist:
            admin_timeout = '36000'
        cache.set('admin_timeout', admin_timeout, 3600)
    return admin_timeout
```

Comment: okay. this is a nice approach.

i changed my approach though. i created an updated_at field in my json data which i stored in my cache. 
whenever i get my data from the cache, i check when the last update was made. this allows me to do an update on my cache to update the value if it exceeds a time frame i don't want